# Can the type of USB 3.0 data cable slow down the transfer speed?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, cable

I have a hard drive that needs USB 3.0 cable to transfer things from my computer. It usually takes 10 mins to transfer few movies.

Recently, my cable broke so I bought a new, longer USB 3.0 cable and now it takes 2 hours to transfer things from my computer to my hard drive. Why is that and how do i fix this?

Comment: the same things? transferring a lot of small files is much slower than one big file

Comment: "longer" might be the problem.  A USB 3.0 cable is limited by its electrical characteristics.  The 3 meter "limit" is based on using the maximum recommended wire sizes.  A cheap cable using thinner wires will fail to meet the requirements at a shorter cable length.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a cable could cause poor performance. And especially if it's a cheap cable, which may not really meet the USB 3 electrical specification.

The other possible reason is that you may have used a different USB port on your computer from what you were using previously, when you were getting 10-minute transfer times. It's quite common for computers to have just one or two USB 3 ports, and a number of USB 2 ports also. If you've used one of the USB 2 ports, that would certainly slow things down also.